# Would having code in a Header tag stop CSS from working properly?

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a mobile navbar like in the example at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_mobile_navbar

My navbar is in a header tag outside of the body.

When I add the icon to the navbar, and try to add a css property to hide it

```
.iconMenu ( display: none; visibility: hidden; }
```

it still shows up. I have been going over SO questions and answers but I can't seem to find a match to my specific issue. I basically want to hide the icon and have my links showing, but on mobile use a @media to invert that and hide the links and show the icon. There are no inline display properties, and my CSS is in its own stylesheet.

Comment: Did you mean to an open curly bracket `{` instead of a parenthesis?

Comment: It would help if you could provide the relative code for better context.